# AFORGE.net with android phone as ip camera

Tags: c#, android, tcp, camera, aforge

Story : I've implemented video streaming application using AFORGE.net, in c# from my laptop camera, using TCP protocol.And it worked excellent.I tested the application on multiple pc's using lan cable and it worked good. I've never worked with IP-Cameras but i read this forum ( http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=36 ) and it says that every ip-cam needs a source string that is a URL in order to connect with AFORGE.net's MJPEGStream class:

```
MJPEGStream mpeg = new MJPEGStream();
mpeg.Login = "username";
mpeg.Password = "pass";
mpeg.Source = "http://ip:port/img/mjpeg.cgi";
mpeg.Start();
```

Problem : Now i want to use my android phone as an ip-camera for video streaming. I've also created an android application that send images continuously to an address using TCP.

All i want to know that if its possible to use android device as ip-camera? And if yes then what source string i should use with MJPEGStream class.?

Thanks in advance for suggestions and guides.

Comment: Were you able to crack this issue. I also have a similar requirement. My PC based solution works flawlessly but I'm looking towards Android as the scene capture device instead of regular web cam. Any inputs appreciated.